# Nginx redirect all media (.mp3 , image , pdf) to MaxCDN origin poll

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx, cdn

I want to redirect all my media files to maxcdn origin poll, this might be duplicate question
but couldn't find the way i was looking for.

**example:**
If visitor request something like : *http://domain.com/monday/day1.mp3* it needs to redirect to *http://xxx.netdna.com/monday/day1.mp3.*

**Question:**  --- No To This :/

*Will nginx allow .htaccess to do this job?*

Or

*Do I need to setup  server config?* How

Here is my config, which is every simple.

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/domain/public_html;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 http://XXX.YYYY.netdna-cdn.com$request_uri;
```

> The page isn't redirecting properly

**Please Help!**

Answer (score 2):

> Will nginx allow .htaccess to do this job?

No. There is no `.htaccess` analogue for nginx.

This will redirect all request to folder `/podcast/` to `xxx.netdna.com`.

```
location /podcast/ {
    return 301 http://xxx.netdna.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I followed directed info.. but wouldn't get it work ;( 
it says
**The page isn't redirecting properly**

Comment: @RupGautam then we need more details. What url you access? Where is it redirects? Full nginx server config.

Comment: You bave config that redirects every request to XXX.YYYY.netdna-cdn.com. Is it what you want?

Comment: So you have this redirect. What the problem? I could only guess that XXX.YYYY.netdna-cdn.com is the same server and you have redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for my problem after a huge dig search on google, but the answer was so simple, didn't realized till it turned on working perfectly for my problem... :)

All I need to add was, following code right after `location /` 
Here is what i added and worked like charm.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```